# How to get div id in cocoa webview xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c

anyone tell me how to get div id from a script webview i used this code but this is not working

```
NSString *strTitle1=[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('div_indicator').innerHTML;"];
NSLog(@"strtil:%@",strTitle1);
```

Comment: "It's not working" means the `strTitle1` variabile is empty?

Comment: ok  can u give any examples

Answer (score 0):

Try this code [Objective-C-HMTL-Parser](https://github.com/zootreeves/Objective-C-HMTL-Parser)
and this [hpple](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple)

and you have this tutorial [How to parse html on iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios)